# creating customized tooltip with image in blackberry java

Tags: button, blackberry, tooltip, custom-controls, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I need to have a tooltip (as shown in below fig) at bottom of my blackberry screen ,tooltip consists with two buttons with image as background for each button .and this tooltip is visible/invisible to user only when menu button is pressed.and by pressing this buttons in tooltip user should be directed to other screen.

[image]

sir i tried below code but clicking on button over the tooltip it is not navigating to secondscreen.what mistake i have done.

### Myscreen

```
 public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
public boolean onMenu(int instance)
{
     int action = Toolbar.push();
     if(action == Toolbar.ACTION_BUTTON1)
     {
      Dialog.alert(" " );
        // UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new 
 SecondScreen());
     }

     return false;
}
public MyScreen()
{        
    setTitle("MyTitle");
}
}
```

### secondscreen

```
 public class SecondScreen extends MainScreen {
public SecondScreen()
{

setTitle("listview");

 }
 }
```

Comment: @Eugene,@Postback could i create tooltip with buttons and image as background in bb java?if possible can you give me suggestion or sample

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when you need a custom clickable field in Blackberry, such as a bitmap with text, it is easier to create a single field that handles the click events. This means extending a field, and overriding the `layout`, and `paint` methods. Trying to do the same thing with nested managers and fields usually gives issues when it comes to navigating with the trackpad or listening to touch events (because a manager is not focusable unless it has a focusable child).

In a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115228/blackberry-how-to-design-the-screen-like-grid-view/24119500#24119500) I made, I gave examples of how to create button fields based on an example from the Blackberry Developer site.
You'll need `BaseButton` and `ImageSubtitleButton` from my post.

Once you have those you should be able to add a status bar to your screen.

```
HorizontalFieldManager toolbar = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
ImageSubtitleButton button1 = new ImageSubtitleButton("test1", "test.png");
toolbar.add(button1);

ImageSubtitleButton button2 = new ImageSubtitleButton("test2", "test.png");
toolbar.add(button2);

setStatus(toolbar);
```

Please note that referencing image resources like this isn't ideal, and you should make a resource manager with constants, as opposed to using inline image names.

**Update:**
Since you want this toolbar to replace your native bb menu, you'll have to override the `onMenu` method which is triggered when the menu button is pressed.
Because you also want the menu to disappear when clicking away from the menu, you are going to have to make a new Screen, with a transparent Background, with toolbar as status.

Toolbar.java

```
public class Toolbar extends MainScreen
{   
     public static final int ACTION_NONE = 0;
     public static final int ACTION_BUTTON1 = 1;
     public static final int ACTION_BUTTON2 = 2;

     private int action = ACTION_NONE;
     private HorizontalFieldManager container;

     private Toolbar()
     {  
          setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(0, 0)); // Make Screen transparent.
          getMainManager().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(0, 0)); // Make manager transparent.

          container = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
          ImageSubtitleButton button1 = new ImageSubtitleButton("test1", "test.png")
          {
               public void clickButton()
               {
                    // Set the selected action, and close
                    action = ACTION_BUTTON1;
                    close();
               }
          };
          container.add(button1);

           ImageSubtitleButton button2 = new ImageSubtitleButton("test2", "test.png")
          {
               public void clickButton()
               {
                    // Set the selected action, and close
                    action = ACTION_BUTTON2;
                    close();
               }
          };
          container.add(button2);

          setStatus(container);
     }


     protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message)
     {
         // Listen for touch events, if they are above the toolbar, close screen.
         if (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.DOWN)
         {
             int y = message.getY(1);
             if (y < getHeight() - container.getHeight())
             {
                  close();
                  return true;
             }
         }

           return super.touchEvent(message);
     }

     public boolean onMenu(int instance)
     {
          // When menu button is pressed again, close
          close();
          return false;
     }

     protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time)
     {
           // When back button is pressed, close
           if (c == Characters.ESCAPE)
           {
                 close();
                 return true;
           }
           return super.keyChar(c, status, time);
     }

     public static int push()
     {
          final Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
          UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
          {
                public void run()
                {
                     UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushModalScreen(toolbar);
                }
           });

           // Return selected action, or ACTION_NONE, if user closed menu
           return toolbar.action;
     }
}
```

Now when you want to use this toolbar on your screen, override the `onMenu` of the screen like this

```
public boolean onMenu(int instance)
{
     int action = Toolbar.push();
     if(action == Toolbar.ACTION_BUTTON1)
     {
           // Handle this button press
     }

     return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood that part. This solution should still work, will just need to be added to the screen in a different way. Will update post

Comment: Slight error on my part, Toolbar should extend `MainScreen` instead of `Fullscreen`, this should fix the setStatus issue. This also means an extra line will be needed in Toolbar to set the screen as transparent. I'll amend the answer. As for the rest, I copy pasted the java files and did not have that syntax error. I wont be able to help you without seeing your MyScreen.java

Comment: The problem is you are pushing Toolbar as your first screen. The idea is you push you other screens as per usual, and override the onMenu of those screens. Ie, Toolbar is only ever pushed via the onMenu method

Comment: Place it in the body of your Screen class. `MainScreen` has a bunch of standard methods that are called for different events and functions. `onMenu` is one of them. I did the same thing with the toolbar (overrode the onMenu of that screen)

Comment: You can't handle the button press like that. The event has already been handled by the toolbar screen. So all you need in that if statement is ` UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new SecondScreen());`

Comment: I'm starting to think that you're not even trying anymore before asking a question. Delegate cannot be null, you need to give it a manager, usually verticalfieldmanager. The easiest is to extend MainScreen instead of Screen

Comment: sorry sir,but i am really not able to get why, on click to particular image on tooltip,  not able to navigate to other screen(secondscreen).it happens like when i click on image only  tooltip disappears with navigating and just stays in that screen.when we want to navigate to other screen we usally use navigationclick() ,but this event as already handled  it is no use here,then whats gone wrong

Comment: You should be able to use `clickButton` instead of `navigationClick`, and would work the way you expect. In your `onMenu` you have an if statement on the returned action. Does this if statement trigger correctly, and the toolbar is removed when it happens? If so, then you don't need to worry about navigationClicks at all, it has already been handled, and the result of which is returned as action

Comment: sir in tooltip there are two images on clicking on particular image it is not navigating to other screen.to check this i used alert in tool.java file inside clickbutton() i got alert on clicking image.but when i put alert inside onmenu in myscreen.java as shown above i am not getting alert instead tooltip closes without navigating to other page remaing in same page.

Comment: Error on my part, the Toolbar push function wasn't blocking. `UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater` should be `UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait`. Will update answer